# Conditionals, if empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I have loop that displays posts. I want to add some html if there will be no posts. Like if there is no posts ---> show my html if/else.

```
      <?php $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1000,
        'post_type' => 'contract',
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
        'post_status' => 'publish' );
      ?>
      <?php $get_category_posts = get_posts( $args ); ?>
      <?php foreach ( $get_category_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li class="jail-app-v-0-4 contract-item">
          <div class="contract-item-inner">
          <a class="hoverable" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </div>
        </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem with adding the `if-else` by yourself? And how should we know what it is you want to show if there are no posts?

Comment: if(mysqli_num_rows... echo else echo https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Comment: Thanks guys, I just don't want to go deep inside that stuff.Below answer was given. THANKS

Comment: Your question is asking how to make a wordpress loop. This is so well documented in hundreds of places, including the manual https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code out please:

```
   <?php $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1000,
        'post_type' => 'contract',
        'author' => $current_user->ID,
        'post_status' => 'publish' );
      ?>
      <?php $get_category_posts = get_posts( $args );

      if(!empty($get_category_posts)):
      ?>
      <?php foreach ( $get_category_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li class="jail-app-v-0-4 contract-item">
          <div class="contract-item-inner">
          <a class="hoverable" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </div>
        </li>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php else: ?>
        NO POSTS FOUND!

        <?php endif; ?>
```